# Three.js texture has fog and is overlapped when zooming out

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

What I am trying to do is adding a simple plain and assigning it a texture that should stretch and fit it. The texture is shown on both sides. So far I have this code (that needs optimization but I need to fix this issue first).

```
$( window ).on('load', function() {

  var container = $('main');

  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true,
      logarithmicDepthBuffer: true
  });

  renderer.setSize( container.outerWidth() - 10, container.outerHeight() - 10 );
  renderer.setClearColor( 0xeaeaea );

  var scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, container.outerWidth() / container.outerHeight(), 2, 1000 );
  camera.position.z = 8;
  camera.position.x = 2;

  var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
  controls.target.set( 0, 0, 0 )

  container.append(renderer.domElement);

  var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    controls.update();

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  };

  animate();

  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 8, 5, 32 );

  var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "texture.png" );
  texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
  texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  texture.repeat.set( 1, 1 );

  var diffuse = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "diffuse.png" );
  diffuse.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  diffuse.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  diffuse.repeat.set( 1, 1 );

  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : texture } );
  material.alphaMap = diffuse;
  material.transparent = true;
  material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

  var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  plane.rotation.x = -60 * ( Math.PI/180 );

  scene.add( plane );
});
```

**1. First problem**

[image: Close look]

When rotating around the plane or looking at it from an angle, this fog is added around the plane. I don't want that. I want the texture to occupy all the plane clearly. No fog, no fading out at the margins. I don't know why that happens

**1. Second problem**

[image: Far look]

When zooming out, the texture changes and is somehow overlapped by itself. I don't know if this is some sort of LOD technique but I don't want it. Like I already said, I want the texture to fit inside the plane and cover it completely, without loosing quality, having fog or changing in any way. I don't know if I need to work with the fog or camera frustrum values. I tried changing them but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add this to the texture to fix this issue:

```
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
```